# How do I save IR codes from my LG Air Conditioner remote and replay them?

Tags: serial, remote-control, ir

I am currently using the following code

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop()
{
 if (irrecv.decode(&results))
  {
   Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
   irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
 }
```

The Serial Monitor is always returning "FFFFFFFF" no matter which button I press.
So I am unable to replicate the signal.

Seems that the IR library doesn't support my LG remote.

How do I save and replicate the signal in this case?

Comment: Try `irrecv.decodeLG(&results)`

Comment: @Gerben Can you be more specific? Where do I put the line of code?

Comment: I tried `if (irrecv.decodeLG(&results))` and am getting the following error msg while complilng.

Comment: In file included from sketch_aug26c.ino:1:0:
C:\Users\Sravan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino-IRremote-master/IRremote.h: In function 'void loop()':
C:\Users\Sravan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Arduino-IRremote-master/IRremote.h:224:10: error: 'bool IRrecv::decodeLG(decode_results*)' is private
    bool  decodeLG         (decode_results *results) ;
          ^
sketch_aug26c:15: error: within this context
within this context

Comment: Sorry. That indeed won't work. Add `Serial.println(results.decode_type);` to get some additional information.

Comment: Perhaps it is wired wrongly? Please test with some other device, like your TV, to confirm the hardware part is OK.

Comment: @NickGammon No, it is wired correctly. Other remotes including my LG DVD player remote work.

Comment: @Gerben I'm getting `11` when I try `Serial.println(results.decode_type);`

Comment: It seems to think it's a SANYO remote. Try looking into recording the raw ir signal. https://gist.github.com/jeje/3027236

Comment: @Gerben I'm getting the following text in serial port `IR code recorded!
Recorded 58 intervals.
Sending recorded IR signal!
Sending recorded IR signal!
Sending recorded IR signal!
`

Comment: You have to modify the code to suit your needs.

Comment: @Gerben I am a noob and I don't know what code I have to modify. Sorry. But here is some more info. The remote seems to send not only the power on signal each time it's powered on, but also temperature and other info. I have no idea how to get the raw codes and decode them.

Comment: You have to just collect a lot of these signals, then paste them into a text file in hex format, 20-30 collected signals may be enough. Then you start looking for patterns in the collected signals. After you have found the repeating pattern and formatted it so that every repeat is on a new line you should convert the hex into decimal and ascii and see if you can see where is the temperature and other data is. You can also upload it to pastebin and tell us what button did you press with each IR code you received.

Comment: @Wally: Did you solve it? I've got the same problem, IRrecvDumpV2 always reads FFFF FFFF from LG air conditioner remote, no matter which key. Also identifies it as Sanyo.